# Meaning of icon configuration in Photoshop Layers panel

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

A video course I am following shows the Layers panel as below:

[image]

When I duplicate the course instructions, my Layers panel shows the following:

[image]

What would be causing the different display?

I am using the Photoshop CC 20.0.1 on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white boxes in the lower screenshot are *Layer Masks*. See this tutorial from [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/layer-mask.html).

A new adjustment layer comes with a white (empty) layer mask. It doesn't do anything as long as it's pure white.

You can delete the masks by dragging and dropping them on the trash can. The person who made the tutorial must have deleted the masks to "tidy up".

Comment: It's not just you - it's the default behavior. The masks have no effect. I've never tried to switch it off, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I was able to delete them using the instructions you provided; thanks so much.

Comment: I can swear I saw an option to disable these default masks, but apparently it's well hidden: I couldn't find it now :)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy, in the Layer panel menu you can turn of default masks for fill layers. Maybe that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: Ah, found it. It's in Adjustments window: there's an `Add Mask by Default` option: http://prntscr.com/mmsm19

Comment: Nice @SergeyKritskiy! I never use that panel. I forgot it existed.